How does Streamingfast's Substreams latency compare to connecting to a Websocket?
Is there any benchmark or resource on the latency of Substreams compared to a websocket to a blockchain node (through services like QuickNode / Infura?) I'm creating a tool to instantly exit my positions for certain tokens when some liquidity pools' prices hit a set point, and want to get the lowest latency solution for this. For context, I want to use this soln across many other blockchains, not just EVM-compatible ones.
Most resources online suggest connecting to nodes directly, but there's a lot of benefits to using a stream (reproducable content basically) that the WSS connection doesn't have, so I wanted to use Substreams if possible. Are there any other considerations I should take into place re: this choice?
To put my constraints in order -

Sub-second latency (Optimally lower) <- This is where I'm stuck.
High reliability - I'll probably be running multiple instances of either to make it fault tolerant, but don't want the connection breaking from the server.
Replicability (Can start from last processed block in substreams).

